# Angular E2E - Error with Selenium/Protractor Config

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I'm trying to use protractor for some e2e testing and have never used it before. The project has been generated using yeoman-gulp-angular and there are some predefined testing tasks/configs. When I try to execute the tasks I see that selenium has started and then the stacktrace outputs a few errors before selenium shuts down. Is there something missing in the configuration?

***Protractor config***

```
'use strict';

var paths = require('./.yo-rc.json')['generator-gulp-angular'].props.paths;

// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  // The address of a running selenium server.
  //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  //seleniumServerJar: deprecated, this should be set on node_modules/protractor/config.json

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: [paths.e2e + '/**/*.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

***Stacktrace***

```
Starting selenium standalone server...
(node:23800) DeprecationWarning: util.puts is deprecated. Use console.log instead.
Selenium standalone server started at http://[IP]/wd/hub

   Stacktrace:
     UnknownError: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"23817.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301326 (093c7e07b4a916b690e784b0374c7f618f1ea4be),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
...
   Stacktrace:
     UnknownError: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
...
Finished in 4.84 seconds
2 tests, 4 assertions, 4 failures

Shutting down selenium standalone server.
```

***Edit***

```
[launcher] Error: UnknownError: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
xpi","e":true,"v":"1.7","st":1486662567000},"firefox@getpocket.com":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.0.5","st":1486662567000},"webcompat@mozilla.org":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.0","st":1486662567000}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/Resources/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"51.0.1","st":1486662567000}}}
```

***Update***

I thought thing were fixed but they are not. After running `webdriver-manager update` and then `webdriver-manager status` I see `chromedriver version available: 2.27 [last]`. When I look in node_modules/protractor/selenium I see `chromedriver_2.12.zip`. Inside node_modules/protractor/config.json I changed the webdriverVersions for chromedriver from 2.12 to 2.27 which is unavailable. Not sure which version I should specify in protractor /config.json.

```
test-mbp:fota-admin-portal test$ gulp protractor:src
[11:48:17] Starting 'webdriver-update'...
selenium standalone is up to date.
Updating chromedriver
downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.27/chromedriver_mac32.zip...
Error: Got code 404 from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.27/chromedriver_mac32.zip
chromedriver_2.27.zip downloaded to /Users/test/project/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver_2.27.zip

/Users/test/project/node_modules/adm-zip/adm-zip.js:19
           throw Utils.Errors.INVALID_FILENAME;
           ^
Invalid filename
```

***Stacktrace***

```
   Stacktrace:
     UnknownError: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"26574.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301326 (093c7e07b4a916b690e784b0374c7f618f1ea4be),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `chromedriver` version you have is pretty old and is not compatible with the latest chrome version - 56 you have

Check out the [Protractor ChangeLog](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for details of chromedriver latest versions

Run `webdriver-manager update` to get the latest drivers and that should fix the issue

You can also check [chromium site](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) for chromedriver vs Chrome compatability

> Latest Release: ChromeDriver 2.27 Supports Chrome v54-56 This release
>   fixes a bug which caused ChromeDriver to fail on pages with
>   SharedWorkers.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the chrome issue but now I see a firefox connection error and I don't have firefox defined in the protractor conf file. Seems to be an issue with selenium and the latest firefox, from what I've read. Question is why is firefox invoked when I'm not even passing it in the config file? See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the below command from command prompt to update the chrome driver from command terminal.

"webdriver-manager udpate"

Once the chrome driver has been update you will be able to run the cases without any issues.

Note - use "webdriver-manager status" to see the version details of the drivers.

Let me know if you have any questions.